# Missing cancel button text in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have an iOS application written in Swift, and the Cancel button in my UIActivityViewController is missing its text. The button is full white. Any ideas?

```
func photoEditViewController(_ photoEditViewController: PhotoEditViewController, didSave image: UIImage, and data: Data) {

    let objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [ image ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.window?.rootViewController?.view
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
        if success {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Done", message: "Thanks for share!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(okBtn)
            self.topMostController().present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    topMostController().present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: { () in

    })

}


func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topController
}
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHGW3.png)

Comment: add this after okBtn and add it to the alert controller
             let cancelBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'cancel button' as a separate action

```
let cancelBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(cancelBtn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set

```
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

That's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```